# Google sheets Script to Hide Rows in Batch

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, batch-processing

I'm currently using this script to hide rows containing 0 on col K

```
function Hide() {

    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
         .getSheetByName('Sheet1');
        s.getRange('K:K')
        .getValues()
        .forEach(function (r, i) {
            if (r[0] !== '' && r[0].toString()
                .charAt(0) == 0) s.hideRows(i + 1)
        });   
}
```

Which works perfect, the only thing is that here when I run the script, it hides row by row (now that I have a lot of rows it takes so much time).

Is there a way to change it to work in batch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make my 'Show and hide rows' script function properly in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54372743/how-to-make-my-show-and-hide-rows-script-function-properly-in-google-sheets)

Answer (score 3):

This is the script that makes the magic

```
  function Hide() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Ventas");
  var currentRange = ss.getRangeByName("RangeCalculation");
  var rangeStart = currentRange.getRow();
  var values = currentRange.getValues();

  var index = 0, rows = 1;
  var show = !(values[0][12] == "" );

  for (var i = 1, length = values.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] == 1 ) {
      if (show) {
        sheet.showRows(rangeStart + index, rows);
        show = false;
        index = i;
        rows = 1;
      } else
        rows++;
    } else {
      if (show)
        rows++;
      else {
        sheet.hideRows(rangeStart + index, rows);
        show = true;
        index = i;
        rows = 1;
      }
    }
  }

  if (show)
    sheet.showRows(rangeStart + index, rows);
  else
    sheet.hideRows(rangeStart + index, rows);
}
```

Comment: It's very good that you shared your solution. It could be better if you include a brief description of your learnings instead of just pasting the code. By the way, you include my suggestion, instead of hideRows(rowIndex) your code use hideRows(rowIndex, numRows) :)

Comment: @Rubén I tried you method nad it runs as slow as the first sample ... Can you please explain few things about yours?

Comment: @AlezShevyakov What things do you need to be explained? (Please reply by posting a comment on my answer)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of hideRows(rowIndex), use [hideRows(rowIndex, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hiderowsrowindex-numrows)

The first form use only one parameter rowIndex, the second use two parameters, rowIndex and numbRows.

Obviously, using the suggested method implies to review the logic of your script.